# useEffect is not firing inside Hoc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, high-order-component

If I had my component without HOC it did fire but now i wrapped my component inside withSpinner Hoc but it does not fire the fetching start.

```
const CollectionPage = (props) => {
  const { isCollectionLoaded, isCollectionFetching } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchCollectionsStart();
  }, []);
  const { title, items } = props.collection;

  return (
    <div className="collection-page">
      <SearchBar />
      <h2 className="title">{title} </h2>

      <div className="items">
        {items.map((item) => (
          <CollectionItem key={item.id} {...props} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  collection: selectCollection(ownProps.match.params.collectionId)(state),
  isCollectionFetching: selectIsCollectionFetching(state),
  isCollectionLoaded: selectIsCollectionsLoaded(state),
});

export default WithSpinner(
  connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCollectionsStart })(CollectionPage)
);
```

here is the console of the state.

[image]

and this is the withSpinner Hoc:

```
const WithSpinner = (WrappedComponent) => ({
  isCollectionLoaded,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  return !isCollectionLoaded ? (
    <SpinnerOverlay>
      <SpinnerContainer />
    </SpinnerOverlay>
  ) : (
    <WrappedComponent {...otherProps} />
  );
};

export default WithSpinner;
```

As you can see from the image, I just see the spinner is spinning becuase fetchCollectionStart is not firing so redux store is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

`isCollectionLoaded` will be true (as I suspect) once dispatch `fetchCollectionsStart` finishes and redux state is updated.

But you have an issue, `fetchCollectionsStart` is only dispatched at `CollectionPage` mount phase which never occurs since `isCollectionLoaded` is false by default and `WithSpinner` blocks `CollectionPage`.

I suggest to move the dispatch useEffect to Spinner Hoc, which makes sense given your code structure. your hoc may look something like:

```
const WithSpinner = (WrappedComponent) => ({
  isCollectionLoaded,
  fetchCollectionsStart,
  ...otherProps
}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
    fetchCollectionsStart();
  }, []);

  return !isCollectionLoaded ? (
    <SpinnerOverlay>
      <SpinnerContainer />
    </SpinnerOverlay>
  ) : (
    <WrappedComponent {...otherProps} />
  );
};

export default WithSpinner
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your property `isCollectionLoaded` isn't being updated, and your view to update the spinner to the WrappedComponent depends on the property `isCollectionLoaded` being changed.

You're already using a [higher-order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) with redux's `connect`, but what you're attempting to do is create a [composite component](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html), with the Spinner and collection searcher. Your instance of `withSpinner` in the second example will need to expose or call the `connect` function, so that redux can do its magic.

By exposing the named component in the first example, you're exposing a React component that has bound logic:

```
export default WithSpinner(
  connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCollectionsStart })(CollectionPage)
);
```

This can be used as:

```
<WithSpinner/>
```

The easier solution, rather than creating a composite component, is to add the spinner to the `CollectionPage` component:

```
 if (!isContentLoaded) {
   return (<Spinner/>);
 }
 return (
    <div className="collection-page">
      <SearchBar />
      <h2 className="title">{title} </h2>

      <div className="items">
        {items.map((item) => (
          <CollectionItem key={item.id} {...props} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```